# Passing pointer of file to DLL from Python

Tags: python, pointers, dll

I have Dll function `int WriteData (const char* buffer);` and I want to pass HEX file or bin file to this function.

My unsuccessfull attempts was smth like that:

```
f=open("FENCEE_Monitor.HEX") # open file
array=bytearray(f)           # convert it 
writeFile=ctypes.c_char_p(array)

dll.WriteData(writeFile)
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

A couple mentions:

- You want to work with (create a *bytearray*, but this is not necessary) the file **contents**, **not** the file **object** itself
- Define *argtypes* and *restype* for functions exported by *.dll*s. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011) for more details

Here's an example for the *printf* function, although it's not recommended to manually load *msvcrt.dll*:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q063411355]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> echo "Dummy text">file.txt
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> f = open("file.txt", "rb")
> >>> t = f.read()
> >>> f.close()
> >>> t
> b'"Dummy text"\r\n'
> >>>
> >>> printf = ct.WinDLL("msvcrt").printf  # @TODO: DON'T use msvcrt this way! This is for demo purposes only!!!
> >>>
> >>> printf.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p]
> >>> printf.restype = ct.c_int
> >>>
> >>> printf(t)
> "Dummy text"
> 14
> ```